# Javascript - my function geolocation permission onchange returns value in a geometric progression

Tags: javascript, geolocation

Here my code that should toggle buttons when user change geo permission

`toogleGeoButtons()` works fine

But when starts on onchange function it causes `toogleGeoButtons()` even times. So

```
function toogleGeoButtons() {
    // toggle function
    console.log("toggled")
}
geoSettings = {
    timeout: 1000 * 10,
    maximumAge: 1000 * 60,
    enableHighAccuracy: true
}
navigatorPermisstion();
function navigatorPermisstion() {
    navigator.permissions.query({
        name: 'geolocation'
    }).then(function(result) {
        if (result.state == 'granted') {
            toogleGeoButtons();
            // console.log(result.state);
            getLocation();
        } else if (result.state == 'prompt') {
            // console.log(result.state);
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(revealPosition, positionDenied, geoSettings);
        } else if (result.state == 'denied') {
            toogleGeoButtons();
            // console.log(result.state);
        }
        result.onchange = function() {
            navigatorPermisstion();
        }
    });    
}

function revealPosition(position) {
    console.log(position)
}
function positionDenied(positionError) {
    console.log(positionError)
}
```

[image: console screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
navigatorPermisstion();
function navigatorPermisstion() {
    navigator.permissions.query({
        name: 'geolocation'
    }).then(function(result) {
        if (result.state == 'granted') {
            getLocation();
        } else if (result.state == 'prompt') {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(revealPosition, positionDenied, geoSettings);
        }
        result.onchange = function() {
            toogleGeoButtons();
        }
    });    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

because you are adding your function multiple times remove navigatorPermisstion(); from on change event.